# Blazor Server and multiple `@page "/"` routes - how is this resolved?

Tags: blazor

I created a .net6 blazor server application.  I noticed that both
_Host.cshtml and Index.razor contain a @page "/" directive.

How does blazor know which one to use?  Clearly it is using the _Host.cshtml version, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#page) tell that this directive has different meaning depending wether it is used in *.cshtml file or Razor component.

Comment: Oh it looks like the difference is razor vs blazor routing...  I guess I did not realize at the time that it was a razor page.  Makes sense now.